# Insert login creditials in php url?

Tags: php, url, post

I am trying to be able to log-in to a PHP webpage with the credentials in the URL.

Example:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/logon.php?logon=user&password=password
```

The URL above inserts user and password into the text fields but does not submit the page and continue.

- How do I submit a page via URL?
- Is it possible? If not, sorry for the question.

Comment: You don't want to embed credentials in a url. They'll be stored as is in the server's access log and readable by anyone. So even if you're storing them with ultra-secure futuristic uncrackable encryption in the database, you've basically left all the username/passwords written on a PostIt for everyone to read.

Comment: I am not worried about it. It is internal. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two versions of the answer, here: how to do what you asked, and how to do what you actually want.  Chances are you don't actually want to do it the way you asked, because passing the password in the URL field is a super-bad idea.  To answer the question as asked, it goes like this:

- To read the values out of the URL string, you can use the $_GET array.  To print what logon is passed, do:

  ```
  echo($_REQUEST[logon]);
  ```

  To submit the data in the first place, you'll need to use a form.  There are other methods, but this is the most basic.  Something like this:

  ```
  <form action="logon.php" method="get">
  <input name="logon">
  <input name="password">
  <input type=submit value="Login">
  </form>
  ```
- That being said, better practice would be to pass the password through the POST parameter, which at least isn't visible in the addressbar.  To do this, simply substitute:

  ```
  <form action="logon.php" method="post">
  <input name="logon">
  <input name="password">
  <input type=submit value="Login">
  </form>
  ```

Comment: It is internal, so I am not worried about getting hacked. I don't have access to the code. It is a website that I want my program to automatically login to. I was just trying to find an easy way out than coding the login stuff into my code. Thanks

Comment: There's no reason to use GET instead of POST, it's not any harder and the form and backend implementation are identical save the switch from method="get" to method="post".

Comment: and if you're trying to work with an existing application, if it's written sanely it won't accept a password through GET anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the website's login system is designed:

- The form: The names of the username and password fields need to be the same as in your url
- The PHP: Most forms use a HTTP POST method to send their data to their server. What you are doing is sending data using a HTTP GET method.

Comment: They are the same. How do I use HTTP POST in URL?

Comment: I don't think you can do that using an URL. You can actually do this with Javascript or PHP (cUrl).